Bottom-up tree structure cumulative sum
CREATE TABLE Emissions (
    entityId    VARCHAR(512),
    parentId    VARCHAR(512),
    emission    DECIMAL,
    percentContribution VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO Emissions (entityId, parentId, emission, percentContribution) VALUES
    ('E1', 'E2', '541', '85'),
    ('E2', 'E4', '272', '85'),
    ('E3', 'E4', '270', '80'),
    ('E4', 'NULL', '362', NULL);

SELECT * FROM Emissions




entityId
parentId
emission
percentContribution




E1
E2
541
85


E2
E4
272
85


E3
E4
270
85


E4
NULL
362
null



fiddle
I have the above tree structure, my goal is to calculate the cumulative sum of each node, with weighted contribution from the children node.
This is what I have so far:
WITH RECURSIVE HierarchyCTE(entityid, parentid, emission, total_emission, percentage, level) AS (
    SELECT
        entityid,
        parentid,
        emission,
        emission AS total_emission,
        percentageContribution,
        0
    FROM
        tree_table
    WHERE
        entityid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parentid FROM tree_table WHERE parentid IS NOT NULL)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        h.entityid,
        h.parentid,
        h.emission,
        h.emission + cte.total_emission * (cte.percentageContribution/100) AS total_emission,
        h.percentageContribution,
        cte.level + 1
    FROM
        tree_table h
    JOIN
        HierarchyCTE cte ON h.entityid = cte.parentid
    
)
SELECT
    entityid,
    parentid,
    SUM(total_emission) AS total_emission
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            entityid,
            parentid,
            SUM(total_emission) AS total_emission,
            level
        FROM    
            HierarchyCTE
        GROUP BY
            entityid,
            parentid,
            level
    )
GROUP BY
    entityid,
    parentid
ORDER BY
    entityid

Expected result:



cumulative_total




541


272 + (541 * 85 / 100) = 731.85 round to 732


270


362 + (732 *  85 / 100) + (270 * 85 / 100) = 1213.7 round to 1214



Actual result:



cumulative_total




541


272 + (541 * 85 / 100) = 731.85 round to 732


270


(732 * 85 /100 + 362) + ( 270 * 85 / 100 + 362) = 1575.7 round to 1576



Formula for calculating cumulative sum of each entity, taking percentContribution into account
cumulative_total(E1) = entity_emission(E1) (Because E1 is a leaf node and therefore has no children entity)

cumulative_total(E2) = entity_emission(E2) + cumulative_total(E1) * percentContribution(E1)

cumulative_total(E3) = entity_emission(E3) (Just like E1, E3 is a leaf node, and has no children entities)

cumulative_total(E4) = entity_emissions(E4) + (cumulative_total(E3) * percentContribution(E3) ) + (cumulative total(E2) * percentContribution(E3))


Welcome to SO, Ngo Chi Binh! Please add table definitions. See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query . Reduce your sample SQL statement to the columns needed (especially in the second half)

@h.m.i.13 Understood, I'll edit my question. However, I'm unsure if I'm using the correct terminology to describe my question. I'm not too familiar with the subject, and web searches for the term 'hierarchical cumulative sum' and 'weighted contribution cumulative sums' seems to return very few to no results.

UPDATED ANSWER:
After clarification of the issues and detailed explanation of expected results (both with and without contribution correction) here is an option how to get the expected result from sample data provided.
It is quite complex, actualy, becaouse you should take care of leaf values and their (future) corrections and of group (parent) corrections.
I called them corrections for it was easer to use them as corrections in calculations compared to contributions - that is why I use (100 - pctcontribution) 100 - 85 = 15% correction on  two levels (leafs and parents)...
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tree_table 
AS 
  ( Select 'E1' as entityid, 'E2' as parentid, 541 as emission, 85 as pctcontribution Union All
    Select 'E2', 'E4', 272, 85 Union All
    Select 'E3', 'E4', 270, 85 Union All
    Select 'E4', NULL, 362, NULL
  );

... Used two CTEs to prepare data
WITH     --  1    R e c u r s i o n :
  Recursive cte (root, entityid, 
                 parentid, entity_emission, pctcontribution) AS 
    ( Select     entityid, entityid, 
                 Coalesce(parentid, entityid), 
                 emission, pctcontribution
      From       tree_table
      Where      parentid Is Null
     UNION ALL
      Select     cte.root, t.entityid, 
                 t.parentid, 
                 t.emission, t.pctcontribution
      From       cte
      Inner Join tree_table t ON( t.parentid = cte.entityid )
    ),

... 2nd cte calculates cumulative total (without contribution) and leaf level contribution corrections
  grid AS      --  2    C u m u l a t i v e    T o t a l 
               --          (without contribution)
    ( SELECT   x.root, x.entityid, x.parentid, x.entity_emission, x.groupid, 
               x.cumulative_total, x.pctcontribution,
               --  Contribution Correction Calculation - entityid level
               Case When x.entityid = x.root 
                    Then 0
                    When x.entityid != x.root And x.entityid != x.groupid And x.groupid = x.root
                    Then x.entity_emission * (100 - x.pctcontribution) / 100 
                    When x.entityid != x.root And x.entityid = x.groupid 
                    Then LAG(x.entity_emission * (100 - x.pctcontribution)) 
                          Over(Partition By x.root, x.groupid Order By  x.entityid)/ 100
               Else 0
               End as contribution_correction
      FROM  (  Select   root, entityid, parentid, entity_emission,
                        Coalesce(LAG(parentid) Over(Order By root, parentid, entityid), parentid) as groupid,
                        --  Cumulative Total Calculation
                        Round( Case When entityid = root 
                                    Then Sum(entity_emission) Over(Partition By root)
                               Else   Case When Coalesce(LAG(parentid) Over(Order By entityid), parentid) = parentid
                                           Then entity_emission
                                      Else Sum(entity_emission) Over(Partition By root Order By entityid)
                                      End
                               End, 0 ) as cumulative_total, 
                        pctcontribution
               From     cte
               Order By entityid
            ) x
    )

... bellow is main sql that has two parts:

a subquery that does group  (parent) level contribution correction calculation
and outer query that results in all your table data an both cumulative totals (without and with contributions)....

--      M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    g.entityid, g.parentid, g.entity_emission, g.pctcontribution,
          -- 
          g.cumulative_total, 
          --  Cumulative Contribution Total Calculation
          Round(Case When g.entityid = g.root 
                     Then (Sum(Case When g.entityid != g.root 
                                    Then g.corrected_contribution
                               Else 0
                               End)
                               Over(Partition By g.root)  
                          +
                             ( Max(Case When g.entityid = g.root 
                                        Then g.entity_emission
                                   Else 0
                                   End) Over(Partition By g.root)
                             )
                         -
                           Sum(g.group_correction) Over(Partition By g.root)
                         )
                     When g.entityid != g.root And g.entityid != g.groupid And g.groupid = g.root
                     Then g.entity_emission
                     When g.entityid != g.root And g.entityid != g.groupid 
                     Then g.entity_emission
                     When g.entityid != g.root And g.entityid = g.groupid 
                     Then g.corrected_contribution
               Else 0
               End, 0) as cumulative_contribution_total
FROM   ( Select    g.root, g.entityid, g.parentid, g.entity_emission, g.groupid, 
                   g.cumulative_total, g.pctcontribution, 
                   Round(Case When g.entityid = g.root 
                              Then Sum(g.entity_emission - g.contribution_correction)
                                      Over(Partition By g.root)  
                              When g.entityid != g.root And g.entityid != g.groupid And g.groupid = g.root
                              Then g.cumulative_total - g.contribution_correction
                              When g.entityid != g.root And g.entityid = g.groupid 
                              Then g.cumulative_total - g.contribution_correction
                         Else 0
                         End, 0) as corrected_contribution, 
                    -- Contribution Correction Calculation - group (parent) level
                    CASE WHEN g.entityid != g.root And g.entityid = g.groupid
                         THEN Max(Case When g.entityid != g.root And g.entityid = g.groupid
                                       Then (g.cumulative_total - g.contribution_correction)
                                             * (100 - g.pctcontribution)
                                             / 100
                                  Else 0 
                                  End) Over(Partition By g.root, g.groupid) 
                    ELSE 0 
                    END as group_correction
        From      grid g
        Order By  g.root, g.groupid, g.entityid
      ) g

/*      R  e s u l t : 
entityid    parentid    entity_emission pctcontribution cumulative_total    cumulative_contribution_total
----------  ----------  --------------- --------------- ----------------    -----------------------------
E1          E2                      541              85              541                              541
E2          E4                      272              85              813                              732
E3          E4                      270              85              270                              270
E4          E4                      362            null             1445                             1214     */

See the fiddle here.
NOTE:
This is not tested against more complex data and there could be some adjustments needed to your actual context.

I've edited my questions for clarity, sorry for the confusion. The percentContribution for each entity is predetermined. Because of the way I'm forced to calculate the cumulative sum of each node, I thought that if I could get the cumulative sum of each entity by traversing from the hierarchy from bottom up, I would have an easier time compared to going top down, sorry for the confusion.

@NgoChiBinh There is still a question how you calculate percentContribution E1 and E3 and how are they the same, exactly 85, while their emissions are 541 and 270, respectively? Is that a fixed value?

Yes, all values in the top table are fixed, any values that you see in my question that isn’t “cumulative_total” are fixed value.

@NgoChiBinh Just posted an updated answer...
